# How do I properly include scripts in my express app when the route is in a sub directory

Tags: url, express, scripting, routes

I have an express app and I'm including CSS and script in the pug template as follows

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js')
```

I'm adding some routes in where the page is /mycollection/create  and this causes the URL or the script to be wrong. What is the correct way of changing the URL of the scripts based on what the route is

Comment: You probably want to start the path to your resources with `/` like `src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"` so it isn't affected by the path of the page and make sure your express routes supports server the resources from `/assets`.

Comment: if you put that as an answer I'll accept it as it worked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to start the path to your resources with `/` like

```
src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"
```

so it isn't affected by the path of the page and make sure your express routes supports serving the resources requested from `/assets`.